# Knockout Validation: how to keep invalid entries out of viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have pages where my Knockout viewmodel performs summary calculations based on user-entered numeric fields. I have the appropriate numeric validation rules in place.

But if the user enters a non-numeric value, the model has to accept the value in order for validation to do its job. So the non-numeric value flows into the summary calculations with undesirable results.

What I would like is for the numeric validation rules to *prevent* non-numeric data from getting into my viewmodel. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

I realize I could use a ko extender or an input mask to reject the non-numeric input, but I would rather the user be notified of their mistake and fix it themselves, rather than simply reverting the user's entry in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution I use is to store the to-be-created item and its values in a seperate part of the root view model, and push it into the list only when (a) validation passes and (b) the user instructs the system to do so. For example:

```js
function Item(name, nr){
  this.name = ko.observable(name || "");
  this.number = ko.observable(nr || 0);
}

function Root(initialItems) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.items = ko.observableArray(initialItems);
  
  self.total = ko.computed(function() { 
    return self.items().reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + parseInt(b.number(), 10);
    }, 0);
  });
  
  self.newItem = ko.observable(new Item());
  
  self.addItem = function() {
    // Stubbing actual validation:
    if (!self.newItem().name()) { alert('name required!'); return; }
    if (self.newItem().number() <= 0) { alert('positive nr required!'); return; }
    
    // Actual work:
    self.items.push(self.newItem());
    self.newItem(new Item());
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new Root([new Item("Apples", 3), new Item("Oranges", 5)]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Total number: <strong data-bind="text: total"></strong>
<hr>
Items:
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: number"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
<hr>
<div data-bind="with: newItem">
  New Item:<br>
  <input placeholder="name" data-bind="textInput: name">
  <input placeholder="name" data-bind="textInput: number" type="number">
  <br><button data-bind="click: $root.addItem">Add</button>
</div>
```